# Implementing "do this, then return that" in function definitions

Tags: function-construction, procedural-programming

In Python, I often use local variables in defining functions, like so:

```
def f(x):
   k = initialk
   < 'do something to k' >
   return(k)
```

I would like to do something similar in Mathematica for instance, I would want:

```
f[x_]:=
For[i=0;k=x,i<x,i++,k=k^2+1];
Return[k]
```

to return $(\cdots((x^2+1)^2+1)^2+\cdots1)^2$.

How does one ordinarily do this in Mathematica?

Comment: `Module`, `With`, or `Block` will do what you're looking for.

Comment: Don’t try to program in Mathematica by reproducing Python practices. You will write inefficient code and end up very frustrated.

Comment: @MarcoB Is there a "Good Coding Practices for Mathematica" somewhere that I could refer to?

Comment: @R.Burton if you asked that as a question, I think you would get some pointers to suitable material.

Comment: @R.Burton For a start, see [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/27951)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want, you could write some thing like this

```
f[x_] := Module[{k = x},
  Do[k = k^2 + 1, {i, 0, x - 1}];
  k]
```

A more natural form would be

```
f[x_] := Nest[#^2 + 1 &, x, x]
```